# How to backup database mongodb using laradock

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, laradock

I cannot backup the database.

Framework: Laravel

Database: Mongodb

Environment: Laradock

Package: spatie/laravel backup

config/backup.php

```
'databases' => [ 'mongodb' ],
```

Run command: `php artisan backup:run`

```
Backup failed because The dump process failed with exitcode 127 : Command not found : sh: 1: mongodump: not found
.
#0 /var/www/vendor/spatie/db-dumper/src/DbDumper.php(246): Spatie\DbDumper\Exceptions\DumpFailed::processDidNotEndSuccessfully(Object(Symfony\Component\Process\Process))
#1 /var/www/vendor/spatie/db-dumper/src/Databases/MongoDb.php(37): Spatie\DbDumper\DbDumper->checkIfDumpWasSuccessFul(Object(Symfony\Component\Process\Process), '/var/www/storag...')
#2 /var/www/vendor/spatie/laravel-backup/src/Tasks/Backup/BackupJob.php(250): Spatie\DbDumper\Databases\MongoDb->dumpToFile('/var/www/storag...')
#3 [internal function]: Spatie\Backup\Tasks\Backup\BackupJob->Spatie\Backup\Tasks\Backup\{closure}(Object(Spatie\DbDumper\Databases\MongoDb), 'mongodb')
#4 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php(1122): array_map(Object(Closure), Array, Array)
#5 /var/www/vendor/spatie/laravel-backup/src/Tasks/Backup/BackupJob.php(253): Illuminate\Support\Collection->map(Object(Closure))
#6 /var/www/vendor/spatie/laravel-backup/src/Tasks/Backup/BackupJob.php(167): Spatie\Backup\Tasks\Backup\BackupJob->dumpDatabases()
#7 /var/www/vendor/spatie/laravel-backup/src/Tasks/Backup/BackupJob.php(143): Spatie\Backup\Tasks\Backup\BackupJob->createBackupManifest()
#8 /var/www/vendor/spatie/laravel-backup/src/Commands/BackupCommand.php(52): Spatie\Backup\Tasks\Backup\BackupJob->run()

#9 [internal function]: Spatie\Backup\Commands\BackupCommand->handle()
#10 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(32): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#11 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(90): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#12 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(34): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array
, Object(Closure))
#13 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(580): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NUL
L)
#14 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(183): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#15 /var/www/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputS
tyle))
#16 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(170): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Objec
t(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#17 /var/www/vendor/spatie/laravel-backup/src/Commands/BaseCommand.php(16): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Componen
t\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#18 /var/www/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(908): Spatie\Backup\Commands\BaseCommand->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\
Output\ConsoleOutput))
#19 /var/www/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(269): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Spatie\Backup\Commands\BackupCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\C
onsole\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#20 /var/www/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(145): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Con
sole\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#21 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(90): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object
(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#22 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(122): Illuminate\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object
(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#23 /var/www/artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#24 {main}
Backup failed because: The dump process failed with exitcode 127 : Command not found : sh: 1: mongodump: not found
```

I tried installing mongo, mongo tools ... to execute mongodump but failed, I found the problem here is that the `workspace` container cannot call a mongodump but doesn't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

`mongodump` is not available in the `workspace` container in Laradock, but it is in `mongo` container.

Anyway mongo container cannot run php so it doesn't help.

Maybe you can change your strategy create a new container called `backup` that will make backups of your app, once started.

You can start from the `Dockerfile` in the `laradock/workspace` directory (and the definition of the container in `docker-compose.yml` file.

Comment: Can you say more clearly, now I don't know where to start.

Comment: You should have some knowledge of Docker to accomplish this. Laradock comes with several Docker images ready to be built and ran (`workspace`, `nginx`, `mysql`, `mongo` etc etc). You have to create another image which will include both php and mongodb executable. I suggest you to dig into docker a bit to understand better this kind of approach.

Comment: You mean running workspace and caching in the same container, I am looking for a solution to the overhaul of Laradock.

Comment: @LeonardoRossi So, do you mean it is possible to create another container that connects to both `workspace` (Laravel app) and `database` (mysql) containers to make the automated backup?

Comment: @Pathros no exactly. You can use the workspace `Dockerfile` as starting point to create a new container that has installed both php and mongo db client